Python in Excel - Change Excel Namespace
Can I alter the namespace of Excel using a Python-in-Excel function?
I can access the excel namespace from python. Let's say, I named cell C17 "my_excel_variable". I can access its value in python:
xl("my_excel_variable")

Now I am wondering, if there is a function, with which I can define my own variables in python, that I can call in an excel-formula.
Whats the application?
In my line of work, we work with standardized material data:

Concrete of class C20/25 has a compressive strength (f_ck) of 20 MPa
and a tensile strength (f_ctm) of 2.2 MPa.
For C50/60 its 50 MPa and 4.1 MPa resepectively.

What is the goal?
I am looking to build a function, that is simply accessed
load_material_properties_to_excel_namespace('C20/25')

after which i can use the properties in excel formulas throughout my spreadsheet
=.85 * f_ck / 1.5

Thank you for your consideration

It is not possible to modify the Excel namespace through a Python-in-Excel function. The Excel namespace is established and controlled by Excel itself. While Python-in-Excel functions can manipulate data, they do not have the capability to directly alter Excel's foundational structure or namespaces.
